# How to make <escape> enter normal mode without changing cursor position in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, it's frustrating to me that the `i` and `<esc>` operations are not mutually inverse. Going from insert to normal mode via escape moves the cursor one space do the left.

Is there a simpler way to change this behaviour than with

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>l
```

which to me seems like too much of a solution. Is there a variable controlling this behaviour?

Comment: What's wrong with `inoremap`? This sounds too specific for there to be a variable you can put in a `.vimrc` file.

Comment: I dislike this solution because it's contingent on the default behaviour of `l`. To me, it's totally jarring that `<Esc>` moves the cursor. I would think there would be a setting, but I don't know how to search for it in the documentation

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11402/why-does-esc-move-the-cursor-back-in-vim

Comment: Note that you have `a` to enter in insert mode to the *right* of the cursor, unlike `i` which enters insert mode to the *left* of it.